# Parallax Scrolling Sprite Kit in Portrait

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm developing a SpriteKit game for iOS and I'm learning to build the game by reading Ray Wenderlich tutorial (Space Shooter SpriteKit)

However I want to make the app in Portrait mode therefore I want to have the background moving from top to bottom.

```
    #pragma mark - TBD - Game Backgrounds
    //1
    NSArray *parallaxBackgroundNames = @[@"bg_galaxy.png", @"bg_planetsunrise.png",
                                         @"bg_spacialanomaly.png", @"bg_spacialanomaly2.png"];
    CGSize planetSizes = CGSizeMake(200.0, 200.0);
    //2
    _parallaxNodeBackgrounds = [[FMMParallaxNode alloc] initWithBackgrounds:parallaxBackgroundNames
                                                                       size:planetSizes
                                                       pointsPerSecondSpeed:10.0];
    //3
    _parallaxNodeBackgrounds.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2.0, size.height/2.0);
    //4
    [_parallaxNodeBackgrounds randomizeNodesPositions];

    //5
    [self addChild:_parallaxNodeBackgrounds];

    //6
    NSArray *parallaxBackground2Names = @[@"bg_front_spacedust.png",@"bg_front_spacedust.png"];
    _parallaxSpaceDust = [[FMMParallaxNode alloc] initWithBackgrounds:parallaxBackground2Names
                                                                 size:size
                                                 pointsPerSecondSpeed:25.0];
    _parallaxSpaceDust.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
    [self addChild:_parallaxSpaceDust];
```

EDIT :

I'm able to move from top to bottom but it doesnt move smoothly.

```
    #pragma mark - TBD - Game Backgrounds
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        SKSpriteNode * bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background"];
        bg.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
        bg.position = CGPointMake(0, i * bg.size.height);
        bg.name = @"background";
        [self addChild:bg];
    }


    -(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"background" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
            SKSpriteNode *bg = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
            bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x, bg.position.y-5);

            if (bg.position.y <= -bg.size.height) {
                bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x , bg.position.y + bg.size.height * 2);
            }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: SO users aren't going to write code for you. Start by trying to implement it yourself, and if you get stuck, tell us what you've tried and where you failed to comprehend a specific issue or task.

Comment: I'm successfully making it from top to bottom, but it moves not as smooth as on landscape mode on Ray tutorial. I will update the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested your code, but maybe +5 points per frame is too many to move the background node smoothly?
Try to calculate amount of points to move each frame:

```
@implementation GameScene
{
    NSTimeInterval _lastUpdateTime;
    NSTimeInterval _deltaTime;        
}

-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if (_lastUpdateTime) {
        _deltaTime = currentTime - _lastUpdateTime;
    } else {
        _deltaTime = 0;
    }
    _lastUpdateTime = currentTime;

    CGPoint bgVelocity = CGPointMake(0.0, -50.0); // Current speed is 50 points per second
    CGPoint amtToMove = CGPointMake(bgVelocity.x * _deltaTime, bgVelocity.y * _deltaTime);

    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"background" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        SKSpriteNode *bg = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
        bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x+amtToMove.x, bg.position.y+amtToMove.y);

        if (bg.position.y <= -bg.size.height) {
            bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x , bg.position.y + bg.size.height * 2);
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Thank you. By the way how can we make the scrolling background only scrolls like in a specific time, let's say for 1 or 2 minutes. how can we apply this in the code?

Comment: This is a subject of another question

Comment: I've been stuck trying to create a vertical scrolling background for a few hours. i guess i wasn't seeing it properly. thanks for your code. it actually helped me correct what i was writing. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to move the sprites dynamically (for example, based on the position of the player relative to the background), and you just want them to scroll by at fixed distance and time, why not do something really simple?!

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
     [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"background" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
          [node runAction:[SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(0, <distance>) duration:<time>];
     }
}
```

`<distance>` and `<time>` are values you'll set based on what kind of speed/duration you want.